# SQL Retrieving and storing integer

Tags: java, sql, select, derby

I have the following code:

```
String query_NoHotels = "SELECT max(id) FROM hotels" ;
ResultSet res = stmnt.executeQuery(query_NoHotels);
logger.info("The result set size is "+res.getFetchSize());
int noHotels = res.getInt(1);
```

However, the `ResultSet` is always returning empty.. I have tested this query on the database and it should be returning `5`.

Is this the correct way to store a result when the result is just one item (an integer)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ResultSet` has a cursor.  The cursor will initially be positioned before the first row (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

You must  call the `first()` method to move the cursor onto the first row:

```
ResultSet res = stmnt.executeQuery(query_NoHotels);
logger.info("The result set size is "+res.getFetchSize());
res.first();
int noHotels = res.getInt(1);
```

Alternately, you can use the `next()` method to iterate through a result set in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please write the code in this way

```
String query_NoHotels = "SELECT max(id) FROM hotels" ;
ResultSet res = stmnt.executeQuery(query_NoHotels);
if(rs.next()){
logger.info("The result set size is "+res.getFetchSize());
int noHotels = res.getInt(1);

}
```

Initially the result cursor is positioned before the first row.So we need to move the cursor to first record by `rs.next()/rs.first()`.